# How to make a depending relation between a class and a component in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm updating the existing documentation of a project I've done. In short, I have to add a new library to communicate the application with a new hardware the client wants to use. So far so good.

So in EA I went to the existing diagram and added a new component. I have a class that acts as controller for the actions this new hardware is going to do, so in the new implementation of the system, this class depends on the new component.

I tried to create a new dependency relationship between them, but when I release the mouse, a popup appears telling me that the connector used between origin and destination elements is not permitted. It prompts me with valid relationships between a class and a component. In that list I can see the dependency relationship, which is the one I'm trying to set up.

This is the popup:

[image]

Any ideas of what am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please check that your assumption is correct, that you are really connecting the valid elements. Try adding the element you want to connect to from the model again to your diagram and see whether you can do it. If this works, the element you are trying to connect to is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, it looks like some other Model validation is in place. What MDG Technologies do you have enabled? Which Toolbox / diagram are you using. 
Go to Settings -> MDG Technologies and try to unselect the ones that are not standard with EA and try again, it must work.

PS - Works fine for me.

Comment: You were right. The problem was a custom model validation set up by the client. Had to use the relationships in this palette, not the basic ones. Thank you!